# postgres - password authentication failed for user ERROR

Tags: postgresql

So I'm not overly familiar with Postgres but I'm following a tutorial on making an web app and it uses Postgres. So I've installed Postgres V14, I initially had to set my my environment variables to enable the command: psql.

When I use the psql command it asks me for a password for my current windows user. I wasn't asked during the setup for a password for this user. So I'm not sure what to put in here.

This is the error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testUser"
```

How can I fix it?